# Disable managed validation rules via API

Tags: validation-rule, tooling-api

I have a requirement to disable validation rules in a managed package via API.

I have tried using the Tooling API and update the validation rule object to deactivate it, but the issue is that I have to provide all of the required fields in an update call(why?) which means it will fail when trying to change the protected validation formula because the rule is managed.

I would like to know if there is a way to update just the Active field without providing all of the required fields?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it via tooling api, but try with Metadata api here: [Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), not sure if it works with Managed Package validations.

Change `Account.TestThis` to your ObjectName.ValidationRuleName

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    String[] validationRules = new String[] {'Account.TestThis'};
    List<MetadataService.ValidationRule> validations =
            (List<MetadataService.ValidationRule>) service.readMetadata('ValidationRule', validationRules).getRecords();
    MetadataService.ValidationRule quickValidation = validations.get(0);

    quickValidation.active = false;
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
            service.updateMetadata(
                    new MetadataService.Metadata[] { quickValidation });
    System.debug(results[0]);
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to test this via workbench maybe?

Comment: Via workbench as in anonymous apex? or Metadata API?

Comment: This workbench https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: You can install the related files from the site in my answer and login to workbench and run the above anonymous apex.